# How do I alphabetize a list based on the nth letter of each word in js

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm working my way through Codewars fundamentals and I need to write a function that accepts two parameters (a string containing a list of words and an integer). The function should alphabetize the list based on the nth letter of each word.

Example:

```
function sortIt('bid, zag', 2) //=> 'zag, bid'
```

The length of all words provided in the list will be >= n. The format will be "x, x, x"

### #

This is what I've got and I'm clearly doing something wrong because codewars just returns 'Unknown error'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    function sortIt(list, n) {
var strArray = list.split(", ");
var newArray = strArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    if(a[n] == b[n]){
      return 0;
    }else if(a[n] > b[n]){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return -1;
    }
    });
return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Hint: JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed. Which letter is `a[2]`?

Comment: That is a very nice hint :)

Comment: n-1 got it. That was silly. Thank you. I also forgot to join the result. Solved it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

n was the position of the number not the index. Silly mistake. Thankyou @Juhana

And I forgot to join the result at the end.

```
function sortIt(list, n) {
var strArray = list.split(", ");
var newArray = strArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  if(a[n-1] == b[n-1]){
    return 0;
  }else if(a[n-1] > b[n-1]){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return -1;
}
});
return newArray.join(", ");
}
```